# Segmentação da imagem com Canny Edge OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, visão-computacional

Estou tentando realizar a segmentação da borda tanto da iris, quanto da pupila utilizando Canny Edge do OpenCV.

Porém todos os parâmetros que usei não satisfazem o critério de deixar bem delimitado as duas bordas. A única forma que encontrei de segmentar pelo menos a borda da iris foi binarizando ela e depois aplicando o Canny Edge, e realmente deu um bom retorno.

- Existe alguma forma de melhorar o resultado ? Ou é tentativa e erro ?
- Como segmentar a pupila?

**Tentativa de segmentar apenas a pupila binarizando no intervalo escuro:**

```
#'guarda' o pixel se ele estiver no intervalo que é preto
for x in range(0,suavizada.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0,suavizada.shape[1]):
        if img[x][y] >=0 and suavizada[x][y] <65:
            escala[x][y] = 255
```

**Codigo para segmentar a iris:**

```
img = cv2.imread('path',0)
suavizada = cv2.medianBlur(img,7)
_,limites = cv2.threshold(suavizada,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

bordas = cv2.Canny(limites,0,0)


cv2.imshow('bordas',bordas)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Imagem original:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem depois de binarizar e passar pelo Canny:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS.:** Estou utilizando Python 3.x com a biblioteca instalada via PyPi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *Canny Edge* da maneira que está sendo implementado está deixando uma pupila muito pequena e similar aos ruídos criados pelos cílios.

Creio que o slice da cor preta seja a melhor opção para extrair a pupila, depois utilizar o [Hough Circles](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html) para encontrar o cículo da pupila e o [Grab Cut](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) para extrair a pupila.

#### Slice no Preto

Extrai da imagem o que estiver entre o intervalo de (0, 0, 0) a (60, 60, 60) do espaço de cores BGR

[image: Slice no preto]

#### Detecção dos círculos

Detecta o círculo da pupila com *Hough Circles*

[image: Detecção do círculo]

#### Região de interesse e Grab Cut

Cria a região de interesse (ROI) com as coordenadas do círculo encontrado e utiliza o Grab Cut para extrair a pupila

[image: Grab Cut]

#### Código

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import urllib.request


resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL10Y.jpg")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

copia = img.copy()
# Extrai as cores entre o intervalo BGR definido
mask = cv2.inRange(img, (0, 0, 0), (60, 60, 60))
## slice no preto
imask = mask > 0
preto = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
preto[imask] = img[imask]

preto = cv2.cvtColor(preto, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Preto', preto)

# detecção de círculos
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(preto, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 100,
                           param1=30, param2=30, minRadius=20, maxRadius=100)

#param do Grab Cut
bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

# pelo menos um círculo encontrado
if circles is not None:
    # converte para int
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    # loop nas coordenadas (x, y) e raio dos círculos encontrados
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        roi = img.copy()
        r=r+50
        # Desenha o círculo encontrado
        cv2.circle(copia, (x, y), r - 25, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        # Desenha o retângulo do centro do círculo
        cv2.rectangle(copia, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
        # Região de interesse com a pupila
        roi = roi[y-r:y+r, x-r:x+r]
        roi_x, roi_y, _ = roi.shape
        #Grab Cut da Pupila
        mask = np.zeros(roi.shape[:2], np.uint8)
        rect = (10, 10,roi_x-10, roi_y-10)
        cv2.grabCut(roi, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
        mask2 = np.where((mask == 2) | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')
        roi_grab = roi * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
        # Mostra o Grab Cut
        cv2.imshow("Grab Cut", np.hstack([roi, roi_grab]))

    # Mostra a imagem com o círcuto e centro encontrado pelo Hough Circle
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([img, copia]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Sensacional! Era isso msm que eu tava me batendo pra fazer, valeu